# MYSQL workbench - location of database file - win 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Where can I find the location of my database on Windows 8 after I created my database in the mySql workbench?

I need the file of the database itself, on internet people talk about the ".frm" files but those are only the tables of the whole database.
Is there actually such an file or do I have to work with the tables files?

Answer (score 0):

There is no singular file that represents the database. MySQL typically has many different files that store the various bits of information that comprise your table.

Even the creaky, antiquated MyISAM database stores index data and row data in separate files per table. InnoDB generally stores all data for all databases in a series of files in the main MySQL data directory, but it can be configured to break those out better into separate files.

No matter how you slice it, there's no way to get your MySQL data into a single file without using the `mysqldump` tool.

Comment: I am making program in Java. Is there such a "main file" in all those data files which I have to make the connection with in Java?
Or do I have to use mysqldump-tool?

Comment: If you're using Java, why not use the JDBC driver for MySQL? The files themselves are worthless without an operational MySQL server process, something the MySQL Workbench tool must have connected to when you created the database.